# mysql show create table in java

Tags: java, mysql

Can I fire show create table query in Java code for mysql?

What I need is complete schema of one database (an old one) in one file and same there is one another database (modified one) schema.

And want to compare schema of both to check difference.

Is it possible?

Why I need in java because I can bild up temporary cooperator that will check sql periodically and give me difference of it in development stage as multiple people are working in project.

Comment: yes it is possible. what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as a simple query. You get back 1 row 2 columns. The first column is the table name and the second column is a TEXT or CLOB with the create table SQL statement.

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("show create table BLA.MY_TABLE");
if(rs.next()) {
       System.out.println("Table Name: "+rs.getString(1));
       System.out.println("SQL Code: "+rs.getString(2));
}
rs.close();
stmt.close();
```

Comment: Please mark this as the answer, unless there is something else missing.